# What is a suitable choice of form for $Y(t)$ for the following nonhomogeneous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is a suitable choice of form for $Y(t)$ for the following nonhomogeneous differential equation?

$(a). y''-8y'+20y=7t^3e^{4t}\sin (2t)-t^2e^{4t}-9\\
(b). y''-8y'+16 y=7t^3e^{4t}\sin (2t)-t^2e^{4t}-9$

***My idea***

for (a) the corresponding homogeneous equation is $y''-8y'+20y=0$

So the axuilary equaton is $m^2-8m+20=0 \Rightarrow m= 4\pm2i$

then $y_c=e^{4t}(c_1\cos (2t)+c_2 \sin (2t))$ how to we find $y_p$ using $y_c$

thank you...

Answer (score 1):

***Little hint for b***

$$(b). y''-8y'+16 y=7t^3e^{4t}\sin (2t)-t^2e^{4t}-9$$
$$(b). (y''-4y') -4(y'-4y) =7t^3e^{4t}\sin (2t)-t^2e^{4t}-9$$
Substitute $z=y'-4y$ 
$$z' -4z =7t^3e^{4t}\sin (2t)-t^2e^{4t}-9$$
$$(ze^{-4t})' =e^{-4t}(7t^3e^{4t}\sin (2t)-t^2e^{4t}-9)$$
$$(ze^{-4t})' =-9e^{-4t}+7t^3\sin (2t)-t^2$$
$$ze^{-4t} =\int -9e^{-4t}+7t^3\sin (2t)-t^2dt $$
$$y'-4y=e^{4t}\int -9e^{-4t}+7t^3\sin (2t)-t^2dt $$
$$(ye^{-4t})'=\int -9e^{-4t}+7t^3\sin (2t)-t^2dt $$
$$(ye^{-4t})'=\frac  94 e^{-4t}- \frac {t^3} 3+7\int t^3\sin (2t)dt+K_1 $$
Evaluate the last integral and you are almost done...
$$I=\int t^3\sin (2t)dt= ? $$
$$............$$